# linux command line for large data set?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

**the problem:** I a large excel file of data, there are over 1000 columns and over 40,000 rows. I have to identify where a given row has a value of >199 in any given cell. **If any row does not have >199 in any given cell then I want to delete those rows.** So that I am left with only rows where at least one cell has a value of >199.

I also have the same data file as a text file, so I was thinking that the best approach might be to use linux command line to do this problem rather than using the excel file (which is bulky to work with given the number of rows and columns). But I am a novice at linux and awk so I was looking for general advice of how to approach this issue? thanks so much

Thank you for your help.

Example image of data set below. Here I would want only the rows that have highlighted cells (because those are >200) but I can't just use the sort function or complicated if than statements because there are so many columns in my data set, so that is too time consuming...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gz3dX.png)

Comment: I don't understand.  Is this a question about Excel?  Have you exported your data from Excel to a text file?  Details, please.   Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Anna did describe her/his case clear. She/He has "the same data file as a text file" and wants to ask for an advice on how to approach parsing this txt file in linux command line and which combination of tools to use for that. Should piping with several commands be used, or some other approach. I am interested in this also. Thank you for the question.

Comment: @titus: I would expect somebody who has been on the site for eight years to know about edits and the revision history. If you look, you'll see that the "same data file as a text file" statement was added after I made my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said *"looking for general advice of how to approach this issue?"* here is one approach:

If you know how to use Python, you could save the file as a comma separated file and run through the file simply by writing a small [script](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/csv/using-the-csv-module-in-python) and then use [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to do something with the data. You can use any operating system that supports python.

Comment: I am just learning python, so I haven't written a script before, what script would do this?

Comment: You could, for example, use the "xlrd" module, in particular its sheet.nrows and sheet.row_values(n) methods. A small tutorial for using xlrd is described on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-excel-file-using-python/

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much general advice. 
Specifically, I advise you to use this awk command:

```
awk '{
        over=0
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i > 199) over=1
        if (over) print
     }'
```

I created a small data file,
based on numbers from your file, and a few I made up on my own:

```
$ cat input
81      23      40
31      0       416     12
2       2       1
157     41      80      201
417     42      17

$ ./myscript input
31      0       416     12
157     41      80      201
417     42      17
```

To *delete* rows from your file, do

```
$ ./myscript input > input.new
$ mv input.new input
```

Notes:

- For your own sake,
  you should decide whether your requirement is > 199, > 200, ≥ 200, or what.
- If you need to keep Row 1 (i.e., line 1, the header row), say so.
- I haven't tested this on a large file. 
  `awk` shouldn't have any problem with a huge number of rows (lines). 
  A thousand columns (fields) *might* be an issue, but I doubt it.